# parent.getMeasuredWidth() and parent.getMeasuredHeight() return 0 in ImageAdapter for GridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

I have 6 drawable images. I put this images in a GridView in 2x3 if it's portraite and 3x2 if it's landscape, but i have a problem: if i try to put measures based on parent.getMeasuredWidth() and parent.getMeasuredHeight();

### first drawable have always 0 as width and hight;

From LOG:

### w: 0 h:0

Code **ImageAdapter**:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;    
    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {mContext = c;}    
    public int getCount() {return mThumbIds.length;}    
    public Object getItem(int position) {return null;}    
    public long getItemId(int position) {return 0;}
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            int width  = parent.getMeasuredWidth();
            int height = parent.getMeasuredHeight();
            int orientation = parent.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
            int vh,vo;
            if(orientation == 1){
                 vh = width/2;
                 vo = height/3;
            } else {
                 vh = (width/3);
                 vo = (height/2);
            }
            Log.e(TAG,"w: "+vh+" h:"+vo);
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(vh, vo));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }    

        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);

        return imageView;
    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.gradient_bg_t1,
            R.drawable.gradient_bg_t2,
            R.drawable.gradient_bg_t4,
            R.drawable.gradient_bg_t5,
            R.drawable.gradient_bg_t6,
            R.drawable.gradient_bg_t3
    };
}
```

Code **MainActivity**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));
    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {

        }
    });
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

it returns zero because the parent view isnt drawn yet. you can post your code to the parent view so it runs after parent view was drawn.

use below code:

```
parent.post(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    int w = parent.getMeasuredWidth();
    int h = parent.getMeasuredHeight();

    ...
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I already tried the code of @Amir Ziarati in ImageAdapter (found it in StackOverflow),  but i can't get the values out of scope.

After i drink a little coffee i changed the code a litle:
I created in ImageAdapter 2 new int variable **w,h**  for width and height:

```
private Context mContext;
    private int w,h;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c,int width,int height) {
        mContext = c;
        w = width;
        h = height;
    }
```

and in MainActivity:

```
    gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    gridview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            int w = gridview.getMeasuredWidth();
            int h = gridview.getMeasuredHeight();
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(MainActivity.this,w,h));
        }
    });

    gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
        }
    });
```

And it's working.